# Does the direct sum have a universal property in the category of groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, direct-sum, universal-property

In other categories, like modules, the direct sum is the coproduct, giving it a neat category theory description. The direct product of groups, which is very similar to it, is the product in the category of groups. And when restricted to Abelian groups, the direct sum becomes a coproduct. The direct sum seems to be a very general and natural construction even for general groups, so it seems like it should have a category theoretic description.

So is there any universal property which defines the direct sum in the category of groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (improperly named) ["direct sum" of a family $(G_i)_{i\in I}$ of (non necessarily abelian) groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups#Generalization_to_sums_over_infinite_sets) (I prefer to call it "restricted sum") is the subgroup
$$\sum_{i\in I}G_i:=\left\{\left.g\in\prod_{i\in I}G_i~\right|~\{i\in I\mid g_i\ne 1_i\}\text{ is finite}\right\}.$$
Its universal property, involving the natural injective morphisms $\varphi_j:G_j\to\sum_{i\in I}G_i,$ is the following:

> For every group $H$ and any family of morphisms $f_i:G_i\to H$ *with commuting ranges*, i.e. such that
> $$f_i(x)f_j(y)=f_j(y)f_i(x)$$ for every **distinct** indices $i,j\in I$ and every elements $x\in G_i,y\in G_j,$
> there is a unique morphism $f:\sum_{i\in I}G_i\to H$ such that
> $$\forall i\in I\quad f\circ\varphi_i=f_i.$$

Comment: This is not a universal property if you need to restrict to commuting ranges. You have to project to make $I$ necessarily commute across your group products.

Comment: This doesn't seem to define the direct sum up to isomorphism. It looks like the direct sum of the Abelianisations would also satisfy this property.

Comment: @ZoeAllen The direct sum $\sum(G_i)_{ab}$ of the Abelianisations does not satisfy this property. Mind the "**distinct**" in my answer and think to the case where $I$ is a singleton and $G_i$ is non-Abelian.

Comment: @Snared I agree with your first sentence but I did not invent this definition of $∑_iG_i,$
 and this is the best which can be said about it. I do not understand your second sentence.

Comment: I apologise, I forgot that part.

Comment: I just mean when $f_i f_j = f_j f_i$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. The condition is $f_i(x)f_j(y)=f_j(y)f_i(x)$ for $i\ne j.$ What would you like to replace it with? I don't understand "project to make I
 necessarily commute across your group products".